# JSON Serialize a map treating key and value as properties with a custom name

Tags: java, json, rest, serialization, jackson

I'd like to convert

`Map<long,long> myMap`    to

```
myMap : [{"key": 1, "value": 100},
          "key": 2, "value": 200}}
```

Is it possible? I am using Jackson and default behaviour is:

```
myMap : [{"1" : 100},
          "2" : 200}}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible with a map. However you can create a custom class with `key` and `value` as fields and then populate a `Collection` with instances of that class. On JSON serialization with Jackson the result will be the way you want it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = "";

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", "mkyong");
    map.put("age", "29");

    //convert map to JSON string
    json = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
```

Comment: Thanks! I have the map inside a very complex structure, I'd like to do it with annotations if possible